# Loop through worksheets and set values

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I am writing the Sheet names and assigning progress in front of it (adjacent cell) from that sheet.

Suppose sheet name is sheet1, sheet2 ... 
I am trying to write

Sheet1  B50 of sheet1
Sheet2  B50 ofsheet2

```
Sub LoadSummarySheet()
Dim row, i, col As Integer
row = 5
col = 3
Range("C5:C15").ClearContents
For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
    If Application.Sheets(i).Name <> "TRACKER" And Application.Sheets(i).Name <> "Sheet1" And Application.Sheets(i).Name <> "PROGRESS" Then
        Cells(row, col).Value = Application.Sheets(i).Name
        row = row + 1
        Range(Cells(row, col + 1)).Value = Application.Sheets(i).Range("B50").Value
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you're after something like this (explanations in comments)

```
Sub LoadSummarySheet()
    Dim row As Long, col As Long
    row = 5
    col = 3

    Range("C5:C15").ClearContents

    Dim forbiddenNames As String
    forbiddenNames = "TRACKER,Sheet1,Sheet2,PROGRESS" 'list sheet names you don't want to be processed

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    For Each sht In Worksheets 'loop through currently active workbook sheets
        If InStr(forbiddenNames, sht.Name) = 0 Then 'if current sheet name is not "forbidden"
            Cells(row, col).Value = sht.Name
            row = row + 1
            Cells(row, col + 1).Value = sht.Range("B50").Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

all this assumes that the macro is being run when Summary Sheet is the active one

if this can be not the case then you can assure to write in the proper sheet as follows:

```
Sub LoadSummarySheet()
    Dim row As Long, col As Long
    row = 5
    col = 3

    Range("C5:C15").ClearContents

    Dim forbiddenNames As String
    forbiddenNames = "TRACKER,Sheet1,Sheet2,PROGRESS" 'list sheet names you don't want to be processed

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    With Worksheets("TRACKER") ' reference wanted "summary" sheet (change TRACKER" to your actually "summary" sheet name)
        For Each sht In Worksheets 'loop through currently active workbook sheets
            If InStr(forbiddenNames, sht.Name) = 0 Then 'if current sheet name is not "forbidden"
                .Cells(row, col).Value = sht.Name ' preface a dot (.) to reference referenced object (i.e. 'Worksheets("TRACKER")' in this case)
                row = row + 1
                .Cells(row, col + 1).Value = sht.Range("B50").Value ' preface a dot (.)
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you that answers my question. Your code is much clean and good to understand.  I am not a programmer i do it to simplify tasks.